# How current induced when magnet moves in coil?

Tags: electromagnetism

How is current induced when a magnet moves through a coil? How does it work? I would like to know how it works and how to explain it in a somewhat simple language.

Comment: Due to changing flux we get and emf and dur to resistance of a loop this emf produces a current

Comment: Maybe you want read https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/336933/faradays-law-of-induction

Answer (score 0):

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/farlaw.html
Hopefully you will understand from this. It is simple really.

Comment: From what I can find this only explains what it is and the equations for it, but what I really want to know is HOW it works, like how you would explain ferromagnetism with something like tiny magnets in the material.